# Solve simultaneous integral equations

Tags: simulation, integral-equations

I am a beginner at mathematica, so I have made huge blunders in my code which gave too many errors so I did not think it would be relevant to post it. I will try and explain my target as well as possible.

I am trying to trace the motion of a particle in a varying electric field. I have the initial position and initial velocity of the particle. The equations are as follows:

$$ r(t)=r(0)+ \int_0^t v(\tau)d\tau $$
$$ v(t)=v(0)+ \int_0^t A.E(r) d\tau $$
$$ E(r)= (B).\frac{p}{pdist^3} + C.z^\frac{1}{3} $$

where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are constants, $p$ is the position vector from the point `{2, 3, 4}` and $pdist$ is the distance from that point.

$r(t),\,v(t)$ and $E(t)$ are in vector forms. vector $r$ is in the form $\{x,y,z\}$ (that is the $z$ which is in equation 3).

I have to simultaneously solve these equations of motion to determine the motion of the particle and make a parametric plot of its trajectory. I have to account for the motion for $t=15$ minutes.

I made a noob attempt which did not work at all. I tried solving all three using DSolve which gave lots of errors. I am also not familiar with how to work with trajectory vectors in mathematica.

Can you please guide me in the direction towards the path which I need to take while solving something like this?

Comment: Some questions: 1.- by using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, you can reduce these equations to just three second-order differential equations, i.e., in terms of $d^2r(t)/dt^2$, 2.- is $C$ a constant vector?

Comment: C is a constant scalar .... the equation given will give the absolute value of the vector E(r) and the direction will be same as that of p....
And I do not understand if the first one is a question or a suggestion.

Comment: Look up `NDSolve` in the documentation. It will likely have examples of solving this type of problem.

Comment: Since I am dealing with vectors, I could not find any example similar to this one.

Comment: @ShivamKaushik, if in $E(r)$ the first term is a vector you cannot add an scalar ($C z^{1/3})$ to it. By the way, what you mean with "absolute value of a vector"? Your problem can be solved, but I need a precise definition of $E(r)$. Oh, my first point before was a suggestion...

Comment: By absolute value I mean the magnitude of the vector $E(r)$. So, in calculation of the magnitude of $E(r)$, only the magnitude of $p$ will be considered. And the direction of $E(r)$ will be same as the direction of $p$.
I apologize for the confusions, this is how the equations are presented....... I also tried to get a $d^2 r(t)/dt^2 form for the equations, but got stuck.... can you please mention them also if you successfully transform the equations.

Answer (score 1):

This is a first approach. I am not sure that the equation for $\vec{E}(r)$ is correct. This is the acceleration vector. Anyway, we should know the values for all the constant, including the values for the vectors at $t=0$, and thus, I assume $\vec{r}(0)=\{2,3,4\}$ and $\vec{v}(0)=\{0\}$. The resulting system of equations cannot be solved with `DSolve`.

I am also assuming from the comments that if the direction of $E(r)$ is that of $p$ the can be expressed then as

$\vec{E}(r)=\left(\frac{B}{\left[\sqrt{(x(t)-2)^2+(y(t)-3)^2+(z(t)-4)^2}\right]^3}+ C z(t)^{1/3}\right)\cdot\{x(t),y(t),z(t)\}$

Therefore, the system is:

$\frac{d^2\vec{r}(t)}{dt^2}=\frac{d\vec{v}(t)}{dt}=\left(\frac{AB}{\left[\sqrt{(x(t)-2)^2+(y(t)-3)^2+(z(t)-4)^2}\right]^3}+A C z(t)^{1/3}\right)\cdot\{x(t),y(t),z(t)\}$

Then, the system of equations can be solved by `NDSolve`;

```
eqns = {x''[t] == (2 A B x[t])/((-2 + x[t])^2 + (-2 + y[t])^2 + (-2 + z[t])^2)^(3/2) + 2 A C z[t]^(1/3) x[t], 
y''[t] == (3 A B y[t])/((-2 + x[t])^2 + (-2 + y[t])^2 + (-2 + z[t])^2)^(3/2) + 3 A C z[t]^(1/3) y[t],
z''[t] == (4 A B z[t])/((-2 + x[t])^2 + (-2 + y[t])^2 + (-2 + z[t])^2)^(3/2) + 4 A C z[t]^(4/3), 
x[0] == 2, 
y[0] == 3, 
z[0] == 4, 
x'[0] == 0, 
y'[0] == 0,
z'[0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[eqns /. {A -> 1, B -> 1, C -> 1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 15}];
{rx, ry, rz} = {x, y, z} /. sol[[1]];
ParametricPlot3D[{rx[t], ry[t], rz[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 15}, 
AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 24, Bold,FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"})]
```

[image]

I do not trust on the problem statement, so its solution. However, this answer intends to illustrate how to solve it with MMA. Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand your approach on converting each expression in the terms of the position vectors (if i am reading it correctly) .... that I think is exactly what I needed. The code although have many errors when i copy and paste the whole thing in mathematica. But it did help me get a direction, thank you :)